# Google Analytics funnel ignore steps

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I have following problem with tracking of Magento purchase on Google Analytics (custom theme, different from default checkout process).

My goal settings are following: http://db.tt/W30D0CnL, where step 3 equals to `/checkout/onepage/opc-review-placeOrderClicked`

As you can see from funnel visualization ( http://db.tt/moluI29d ) after step 2 (Checkout Start) there are a lot of exits toward `/checkout/onepage/opc-review-placeOrderClicked` which is setted as step 3, but step 3 reporting always 0.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. Apparently second point (`/checkout/onepage`) was fired even on the third step.

When I changed it to regex match (/checkout/onepage$) everything started to work.